# What is the correct country name to send mail to the Island of Saba?

Tags: usa, netherlands, shipping

I use a virtual mail box in the USA and I need to have them forward a letter to me on the Island of Saba in the Caribbean. It's part of the Netherlands.  What country name should I use so the US Postal Service sends it to the right place?  If I say "Netherlands," I'm afraid it'll get mis-sent to Europe, but Saba isn't a country.  I've seen several different answers online (Dutch Antillies, Netherlands Caribbean, others) but I can't figure out what the official one would be for the USPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The USPS [advises you to address such mail](https://pe.usps.com/text/imm/ab_026.htm) to the "country" of "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius, and Saba". So you should probably address your mail as something like:

```
Mx. X.
[local street or box number]
Saba
BONAIRE, SINT EUSTATIUS, AND SABA
```

The current pandemic is making worldwide logistics troublesome, and this is probably not a destination to which the USPS sends a lot of mail even during normal times, so it might take a bit of time for your mail to arrive, and it is even possible it gets lost entirely in the bowels of some postal office somewhere in the world. You might want to test with some non-critical correspondence if possible.

Comment: If the OP is mailing from the USA, following the guidelines/suggestions of USPS is key.  All USPS needs to do is get it out of the country to Saba.  Local post in Saba likely don't care what you put, as they don't need that information.  Local post looks at the local address

Comment: Sometimes USPS counter workers are clueless about international addressing. Last year, we mailed a letter to our cousin in Belfast, and contrary to the USPS addressing guidelines the counter person insisted the letter be addressed to "...Belfast, Northern Ireland, UK." The letter disappeared into the mail system for weeks, then was returned to us with "No such address" endorsed. I agree that a test (as suggested in mlc's Answer) is desirable. If the US-to-Saba letter is submitted over a USPS counter, have a printed copy of the USPS webpage in hand, just in case.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica what do the USPS addressing guidelines say?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I just spent more time than I should have looking on the USPS website, and all I found was "The last line of the address must show only the country name, written in full (no abbreviations) and in capital letters."  I don't believe, however, that they really want the last line of the address to be `UNITED KINGDOM OF GREAT BRITAIN AND NORTHERN IRELAND`.

Comment: postal workers are smart in easy/common cases; I'm sure if you want to send a letter to London, "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "United Kingdom" or "England" will work. I once sent myself a postcard in the opposite direction and forgot to write the country entirely, but luckily somebody in the British postal system knows where "New York, NY" is, and it arrived without trouble. Less-common cases are less likely to work so magically, though, and especially with covid-related worldwide logistics disruptions, it seems possible for even properly addressed mail to disappear

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica "special municipality": so that's how they're translating it.  The Dutch term is _openbaar lichaam,_ which literally means "public body."  The word for municipality is different _(gemeente,_ being I suppose a calque of French _commune),_ but "public body" is so unspecific and liable to misunderstanding that I could never think of what to call these entities in English.

Comment: @phoog The reference page I previously consulted is probably in the Royal Mail's webpages about formatting UK addresses. In our case, the correct address format (here anonymized) was Ms. Z, 111 Whatever St., Belfast BT6 5AH, County Antrim, UK. (We never expand "UK.") Saba turns out to be a "Special Municipality" of the Netherlands, but as mlc advises, the USPS considers it to be within the "country" of "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius, and Saba," likely a _de facto_ local post operation. I'd address OP's letters to "Mr. X, (local address, street, or box), Saba, BONAIRE, SINT EUSTATIUS, AND SABA."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica and phoog, thanks, I've expanded and clarified my answer a bit based on your feedback.